# Access cached DNS entries when main DNS-server is down?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, hostname, lookup

I try to access `subdomain.a.com` which uses `dns.b.com` for DNS but that DNS-server (all 10 of them actually) is down since about 2 hours. subdomain.a.com is working as expected but you just can't access it using its domain name.

I am no expert in this but AFAIK it typically takes 24-48 h for a DNS-change to propagate. Shouldn't I be able to look up `subdomain.a.com` using the `host` command and asking it query e.g., Google's or Cloudflares DNS-server (8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1)? I tried that but didn't get an response (`Host subdomain.a.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`).

I have also tried the services at https://dnshistory.org/ and https://completedns.com/dns-history/ but didn't the didn't have any data for this domain (I guess it might be because it is a subdomain).

Are there other ways to find out the IP-address for a site where the DNS-servers temporarily are unavailable?

Answer (score 3):

> I am no expert in this but AFAIK it typically takes 24-48 h for a DNS-change to propagate. Shouldn't I be able to look up subdomain.a.com using the host command

*Sometimes,* yes. But the description of DNS changes "propagating" probably gives the impression that they are pushed out around the world and every DNS server (Google, Cloudflare, etc.) keeps a cache of every domain in existence. That's not how it works, though.

In reality, once a change is made, the new information is sent *only* to the domain's own name­servers<sup>1</sup> (the ones which you're saying are down), while the rest of the world does not receive it at all.

Outside of that small circle, DNS is actually a 'pull'-based system where the caches are built up **on demand** as the (Google or Cloudflare or ISP) DNS servers receive queries for specific names. Until at least one query for "subdomain.a.com" is made to Google's DNS server, it knows nothing about that domain.

Second, the cache entries expire after a certain time (the "TTL" set by the domain's owner, which can indeed be 24 hours, but can also be as high as 1 week or as low as 1 minute). if your domain had a TTL of e.g. 1h, then Google would only cache the results for one hour *after a query was made*; after that the entry disappears and a subsequent query will cause the data to be retrieved anew (giving the illusion that it takes 1h to "refresh" the data).

Finally, because both Google and Cloudflare in particular use *anycast* for their 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1 addresses – the same IP address is represented by many servers around the world, each of which has its own cache – those cache entries are more or less local to you. The same entry might be still cached for several hours in the 8.8.8.8 instance that serves New York, but not cached at all in the instance that serves London.

So if all of the domain's nameservers are down, you will be able to query the cached information *only if* an earlier query caused it to be actively 'pulled' and cached on that particular server.

---

(<sup>1</sup> And even that is not guaranteed; there are still domains using the old-style setup where even its authoritative nameservers replicate on a set schedule, e.g. hourly, instead of immediate replication. That's another origin of the "24-48h" that's often repeated – many TLDs used to only deploy changes hourly or even daily.)

> I tried that but didn't get an response (Host subdomain.a.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)).

That's a very different issue. You **did** get a response; "Not found (NXDOMAIN)" is the result from a successful lookup – a negative result but nevertheless a result that came all the way from the authoritative DNS servers of that domain. (It's also cached the same way positive results are, with a TTL.)

So getting NXDOMAIN indicates that "dns.b.com" wasn't entirely down – it was up and actively claiming that the subdomain didn't exist in its database (either now, or at the time that the negative result was cached).

"SERVFAIL" is what you would get if the cache server was truly unable to contact the authoritative DNS servers and get a response from them.